# What exactly is a cyclic graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Can a cyclic graph look like n-butane, a linear organic molecule? Do cyclic graphs have to be circular?

Comment: A cyclic graph is simply one that contains a cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n-butane contains only C and H atoms and no rings. A graph representation in which the graph vertices represent the atoms and the graph edges represent the connections between the atoms does not contain any cycles (rings). Cyclobutane however contains a ring so could be represented with a cyclic graph.

Cyclic graphs contain cycles i.e. it is possible to find a path from a starting vertex traversing a set of unique edges and ending up back at the starting vertex.

Answer (score 5):

[A cyclic graph is a graph containing at least one graph cycle.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicGraph.html)

So for connected graphs, anything that isn't a tree.

Comment: Oops, I somehow assumed connectivity. edited